# PHP Server Sent Event (SSE) Not Working In My New Hosting Server

Tags: php, curl, server-sent-events

I have SSE script which reads feed stream from the remote server. That remote server serves all the output in return. My script is working fine to my other servers and even into local pcs using localhosts.

However, when I use the same script to my new server it is not working and keeps loading.

**NEW SERVER DETAILS, WHERE MY SSE CODE IS NOT WORKING**

- cURL is working fine into the new server, I tested by doing call without sse
- The new server is CentOS 8
- Apache/2.4.37
- PHP Version 7.4.2 and it's working fine
- There is no issue with SSL but just for information SSL is installed

Following is my code which is working fine to my all other servers and into local hosts.

**Note:** I have replaced username, password and remote server URL with dummy one. But I am using the same script to a new server with all the correct details.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$gwuser        = "USERNAME";        
$gwpass        = "PASSWORD";

if(!empty($gwuser) && !empty($gwpass)){
        $url = 'https://example.com/gateway/stream';    

        ini_set('output_buffering', 'off');
        ini_set('zlib.output_compression',false);
        ini_set('implicit_flush',true);

        while (@ob_end_flush());
        ob_implicit_flush(true);

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $gwuser . ':' . $gwpass);

             $error  = 0;

            //This while loop is only for server timeout after 5 minutes
            while(true) {
                $result = curl_exec($ch);
            }

    }
?>
```

Please note that normal sse is working where i can continuously print current server time, So i doubt its failing while doing cURL call to remote server. Also into remote server there are no firewall or domain level filter enabled.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Not working means, Whenever i run this script it should start showing output, The feed from remote server. This is normal behavior while running into any other server and even into localhost local pc. For trial and test purpose I disabled zlib.output_compression = Off into php.ini along with output_buffering = Off in my new server

Comment: And what have you tried to **debug** the problem? For example, there are debugging flags for cURL

Comment: Actually there is no issue into cRUL because after long wait i get init output ie. http://prntscr.com/rcjj3x. 

Which started immediately into all other servers. I should get feed from remote server after this init output and this INIT output should come without any delay not after loong wait.

Comment: Once more: and what have you tried to debug anything? If you are sure that cURL is working, what about searching for a difference between both server configurations?

Comment: thanks nico, Sorry, but for debug i checked my cURL functioning, verified script code, tested normal sse to print current time. And then after I compared phpinfo() details into server and made changes to buffer, memory, execution time, zlib.output_compression, output_buffering etc. But those changes didnot made any solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209160/discussion-between-vipul-ghetiya-and-nico-haase).